# I came across classes separated by |. What does this do exactly?

Tags: html, jstree

While working on `jstree` I came across this line of code-

```
<!-- one of the three classes will be applied depending on node structure -->

<li class="[ jstree-open | jstree-closed | jstree-leaf ]">
```

What does this mean?

Comment: I'm not really sure about | and those [] , for assigning multiple classes to an element, they can just be separated by white spaces.

Comment: It means what it says on the tin: *one* of the three classes will be applied on each element, depending on its state and the structure of the tree.

Comment: i suspect someone got fancy and decided to put in [|] because they thought it was easier to read.

Comment: @xFortyFourx Thanks, but that was not the question here. I need to know what the [] and | means while adding classes.

Comment: @cloudYturtle: It means nothing, and neither does it exist. It's there purely just to get a point across.

Comment: my guess would be that the class string gets manipulated by jstree's javascript functions in such a way that the displayed node in the tree has only one of the three classes. AFAIK this is not a html class definition with any special functionalities

Comment: @cypherabe: *That string is not used anywhere except inside the documentation*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a verbatim example of what the resulting HTML will look like -- it's just pseudo-HTML to help developers understand what's going to happen at runtime. There are no square brackets and no pipes in either the code or the resulting HTML. It's just *documentation*.

It means that when the tree is rendered, *one* of the three classes will be applied on each element depending on its state and the structure of the tree.